# Facebook Change FBML Tabs Icon

Tags: facebook, icons, fbml

How can I change the FBML tabs Icon from the default one to a custom one, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does have an icon with the new layout and it looks terrible.

Found this video about changing your own app's icon: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIcG5VekxM0

But that doesn't apply to the FBML tab (since it is not my app).

Comment: Yup, so you can't change it, GREAT... Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, FBML tabs doesn't have an icon, just text.

Maybe do you want to change your facebook app icon that appears on the user's app menu on the sidebar?

If it's this, you can change it on the app settings, there are two images to upload: one will appear on the permissions dialog and the other is the 16x16px that I've mentioned before.

Comment: Hi, Manuel. The new Page layout with tabs on the left site show small icons. For example the "Resources" tab for the Facebook page on Facebook: http://www.facebook.com/#!/facebook.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly have an answer but because my question is exactly the same as yours, I thought I'd add on here. But do tell me if I shouldn't be doing this and I'll remove it immediately.

I see [ChickFilA](http://www.facebook.com/ChickfilA) uses customised icons for their tabs. Wonder if they developed their own app(s) thus the ability to customise the icon(s), or if there really is a way to customise FBML icons.

Comment: Hi, Hasanah. Interesting. I'm not sure if that's an application tab. I remember reading about Facebook wanting to remove application tabs, I might be wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

There's no icon for FBML tabs. But there's an icon for an application based Facebook tab. Here's how.

1. Create a Facebook app that can be integrated as a tab (Choose Page Tab Type as FBML)
   E.g. Chick Fila created Spicy Biscuit app http://www.facebook.com/#!/ChickfilA?sk=app_119130604778515 that actually was later rendered as a Facebook tab (named Spicy Biscuit)
   When you create an app, you can add an icon.
2. Submit your app to the Facebook app directory (Your application must have at least 5 total users or 10 monthly active users before you can submit it)
3. Now, go to the application page. E.g. Chick-fila Spicy Buscuit http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=167096109994873
4. Click Add to my page. Add it to the page you want to the tab embedded.

Done.